# Misbehaving arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a class, looks something like this:

```
function MyClass()
{
    this.array1 = [];
    this.array2 = [];
    this.add_item = function( i_x, i_y, i_item )
    {
        var pos = { "x" : i_x, "y" : i_y, "data" : i_item };
        this.array1.push( pos );
        this.array2.push( pos );
    }
    return this;
}
```

What is happening is that when I put a breakpoint at the second row of the add_item method (the this.array1.push row) both array1 and array2 already have the pos item! When I step forward one step, **both** arrays receive the pos item again!

The unlikely answer is that this is a bug in Firefox. I experimented a bit earlier with prototyping in methods into Object, but then read that that could lead to problems with for-each-loops. What could be causing this? Is the old code still bouncing around in there? I need a clue. I've removed all Array and Object prototype code I had. I've restarted firefox. Nothing helps. Any ideas?

Comment: Experience has taught me that if I think the bug lies in the programming language, or browser (in this case), then most likely the bug is in my code.

Can you post the code where the object of `MyClass` is being instantiated, and how is the `add_item` method being called?

Comment: This is certainly my experience also (that is why I said that it was unlikely to be the problem). Turns out the bug was in Firebug, though. It's not printing the arrays correctly in the variable viewer. Printing the array with my own function shows it contains the correct entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with the firebug debugger. It was not showing the actual array. I'm not sure what it is showing, but I implemented my own object-printing-method (that handles cyclic object references) and it turns out the arrays are correct.

*phew* thought I was going nuts there for a while.